# Create column based on values on another column in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dml

Suppose I have the following  table:

```
|---------------------|
|          id         |
|---------------------|
|          12         |
|---------------------|
|         390         |
|---------------------|
|          13         |
|---------------------|
```

And I want to create another column based on a map of the `id` column, for example:

```
12 -> qwert
13 -> asd
390 -> iop
```

So I basically want a query to create a column based on that map, my final table would be:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|
|          id         |          col        |
|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         |          qwert      |
|---------------------|---------------------|
|         390         |          iop        |
|---------------------|---------------------|
|          13         |          asd        |
|---------------------|---------------------|
```

I have this map in a python dictionary.

Is this possible?

(It is basically `pandas.map`)

Comment: Do you wish to perform this operation within Redshift? If so, the 'map' needs to be available as a table within Redshift and it would just be a matter of JOINing to the map table. What does your map look like? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: It is a python dictionary (actually, my real problem is because I had a pandas dataframe that I uploaded to redshift but I forgot one column I don't want to create and upload the entire table again, I would like to just pass that column and the primary key of the table :)., I think that solution of creating a new table and JOIN with the initial one as you said will work. But I was wondering if there were a possibility, for example, to pass two lists in a SQL query and use those lists as `(key, value)` pairs to create another column based on an initial one (the primary key). @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you wish to "fix" some data that is already in your PostgreSQL database.

You could include the data using this technique:

```sql
WITH foo AS (VALUES (12, 'qwert'), (13, 'asd'), (390, 'iop'))
SELECT table.id, foo.column2
FROM table
JOIN foo ON (foo.column1 = table.id)
```

You could do it as an `UPDATE` statement, but it gets tricky. It would probably be easier to craft a `SELECT` statement that has everything you want, then use `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT...`

See: [CREATE TABLE AS - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html)

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was searching for, thanks